# How to Import a constant of an user id from another file

Tags: discord.js

I've been trying to import a constant with an user id from another file for a while but it shows up as undefined. Basically I want to use the user that this constant gets

```js
const user = interaction.options.getUser("target");
```

in another file, the "target" here is the user that the slash command author is mentioning when using a slash command, I want to use it in a button handler to be specific, and use it in this

```js
            .setDescription(`${interaction.user} has given a like to ${user} `)
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to get the user that the constant obtains as all I've tried so far has resulted in "undefined" showing up and not the user. any help is appreciated

Comment: Easy button support is one of the weaker parts of discordjs v13 :( Nonetheless, I don't think the use case you're planning is going to support what you want. Interaction slash commands are not built at runtime, they are premade and cached. So setting option.setDescription would not be useful.

Answer (score 0):

So you can do this. The first block of code is for the embed that has the buttons and is simple.

```js
.setFooter({
    text: `${user.id}`
})
```

This block will go in your `interaction.isButton()` section for the code that works when they click the button to confirm

```js
const member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.message.embeds[0].footer.text)
console.log(member)
```

Comment: It said [Object object] so I changed "user" to "user.username" on the second code but now I'm getting undefined again

Comment: So file1 should not be a command (which is where `interaction.options.getUser` would be) you need to set that under your `client.on('interactionCreate'` event listener, I'm updating my answer to show what it should be, and there is actually a way easier way, that will be listed as "part 2"

Comment: Answer updated now

Comment: Now unless you are trying to define a user being someone who isn't using the command, then that will require a different code, if that is the case let me know which should also go to make a statement that if you need the user defined in a command somewhere else in another file, I'd have to get WAY more information about what is attempting to be done.

Comment: Yeah, it's a different user, what I'm basically trying to make is a command that let's you give likes to other users and have them show on their profile, and for that I made a slash command that obviously also prompts you to select an user to give the like to, in this case, that user you want to give a like to is "target", that's the first code I posted, and when you do an embed with 2 buttons(confirm/Cancel) shows up , that works fine and it also shows the avatar of the "target", however I have a Button Handler to avoid huge files

Comment: This means I need to export the ID of said "target" that the first code gets, into the Button Handler file, otherwise it won't work because there's no ID to mention said "target" again or assign likes to since the ID is on another file, I tried module.exports but it just shows up as undefined. Basically I'm not trying to get the user who used the command, that works just fine with interaction.user, I just need to get the user who got mentioned by the user who used the command, the first code I posted does that but I've been unable to export said "target" into the button handler

Comment: Updating answer with a solution